# Elasticsearch query for nested AND OR clause for this simple scenario

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 fields - **name** and **color**. my data looks like below

| id | name | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mango | green |
| 2 | mango | yellow |
| 3 | banana | green |
| 4 | banana | yellow |
| 5 | pineapple | green |
| 6 | pineapple | yellow |
| 7 | melon | green |
| 8 | melon | yellow |

I am looking for **(yellow mango)** or **(yellow or green banana)** from search api. Meaning i am looking for id **2,3,4** in the search result

I am building query like below that I have got from **_sql/translate** api
but this search is always giving me **(yellow or green banana)** or **(yellow and green mango)** meaning it is giving me **1,2,3,4** in results -

```
{
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "name": {
                    "query": "mango"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "color": {
                          "query": "yellow"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "name": {
                    "query": "banana"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "color": {
                          "query": "yellow"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "color": {
                          "query": "green"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

While I am still working to find correct query, if you have any input that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of nesting here which is not required. Remember `bool` is to combine multiple queries into an `AND` / `OR` relationship.

So the main issue is that `yellow` is a should for you. But it should be a `must`. Also, if you are boosting everything equally no need to boost.

```
{
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "name": {
                    "query": "mango"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                      "match": {
                        "color": {
                          "query": "yellow"
                        }
                      }
                
              }
            ]
        },
        {

            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "name": {
                    "query": "banana"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "color": {
                          "query": "yellow"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "color": {
                          "query": "green"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you query is having some `parsing_exception`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below search query to achieve your required results

**Search Query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "name": "mango"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "color": "yellow"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "color": "yellow"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "color": "green"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "must": {
                            "match": {
                                "name": "banana"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "75557106",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 2.3487744,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "mango",
                    "color": "yellow"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "75557106",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 2.3487744,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "banana",
                    "color": "yellow"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "75557106",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 2.1817203,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "banana",
                    "color": "green"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I see the problem now. If the color is simple text like green, yellow, the OP's query works. But if they have any special character it fails to work both OP and answers. For example, my colors look like green::1,yellow::2. This : is causing the problem to get me the results. Is there anyway to escape that? I tried using backslash but they fail.